# How to find the number of machines given a set of rental prices?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, word-problem

I'm stuck in a situation involving rental. Typically I would assign a set of constants based on their price but I'm confused on how to use it or if it applies here.

The problem is as follows:

> A tv station in Kaohsiung hires the services of a Germany-based
>   company which rents a set of equipment for tv-show production being a
>   total of $19$ with these being tv cameras, video editing consoles and
>   3D chroma key graphics computers with rental cost of $80$, $50$ and
>   $60$ $\textrm{USD}$ respectively for which obtains a profit of $\textrm{1240 USD}$ per week. 
>   If the company whose rents the equipment raised their rent prices in $\textrm{20 USD}$ for each tv camera and raised 
>   $\textrm{10 USD}$ for each chroma key computers and decreased in $\textrm{10 USD}$
>   the rent costs for each video editing consoles the profit would become
>   into $\textrm{1420 USD}$ per week. How many video editing consoles
>   does the company rents to the tv station?

What I tried to solve this particular problem was to build up a system of equations as follows:

I assigned the letters:

$$\begin{array}{c} \textrm{t, for tv cameras,}\\ 
\textrm{v, for the video editing consoles}\\ \textrm{c, for the chroma key}\end{array}$$
Short reference: [Chroma key graphics computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key), so they would represent the number of items respectively.

Since it is mentioned in the passage that what the company would obtain by a week is $1240\,USD$ I'm not worrying about the days as the latter passage of the problem also compares it with what will be obtained in a week being $1420\,USD$. So the convertion factors would be the dollars per number of objects. With that in mind I came up with this equation.

For the first part this would become into:

$t\times \frac{80\,\$}{\textrm{1 tv camera}}+ v\times \frac{50\,\$}{\textrm{1 video console}} + c \times \frac{60\,\$}{\textrm{1 chroma key computer}} = 1240\,\$$

In the second part it alludes that the price is riased for the tv cameras and chroma key computers and decreased for their chroma key computers, so I figured that it would be like this:

$t\times \frac{\left(80+20\right)\,\$}{\textrm{1 tv camera}}+ v\times \frac{\left(50-10\right)\,\$}{\textrm{1 video console}} + c \times \frac{\left(60+10\right)\,\$}{\textrm{1 chroma key computer}} = 1420\,\$$

Finally the last part would account for the total number of objects becoming into.

$t + v + c = 19$

Organizing all the three would be this system of $3 \times 3$ : (note that purposes of brevity and better displaying I ommited the wording and labels placed in the previous equations)

$$\begin{array}{c}80 t + 50 v + 60 c = 1240 \\
100 t + 40 v + 70 c = 1420\\
t + v + c = 19\end{array}$$

Now there are many methods for solving this system but I preferred to use simple substitution of the first variable on the second and third rows.

By simplifying:

$$8t + 5v + 6c =124$$

$$8t = 124 -5v -6c$$

$$10t +4v + 7c= 142$$

Now I'm multiplying by $5$ to the $8t$ and by $4$ to $10t$ so it can be better replaced one onto the other.

$$5 \left( 8t = 124 -5v -6c \right)$$

$$4 \left( 10t +4v + 7c= 142 \right)$$

$$40 t = 620 - 25v - 30c$$

$$40 t + 16v + 28c = 568$$

Replacing the first in the second one becomes:

$$\left(620 - 25v - 30c\right) + 16v + 28c = 568$$

$$- 9 v - 2 c = -620 + 568 = -52$$

$$9v + 2 c = 52$$

Now all is left to multiply by $40$ to the third equation in the system so it can easily be substitued using the second expression:

$$40 \left(t+v+c=19\right)$$

$$40t + 40 v + 40 c = 760$$

Therefore:

$$\left(620 - 25v -30c\right) + 40v + 40c = 760$$

$$15v + 10c= 760 - 620 = 140$$

In short the remaining equations left are

$$\begin{array}{c}9v + 2 c = 52\\
  15v + 10 c = 140\end{array}$$

Simplifying the second one:

$$3v + 2 c = 28$$

So now all that is left is to multiply by $-1$ to any of both, which I used the second to obtain a quicker subtraction in the right side of the equation

$$-1 \left( 3v + 2 c = 28 \right)$$

$$-3 v - 2 c = -28$$

So all the two together becomes into:

$$\begin{array}{c}9v + 2 c = 52\\
 -3v - 2 c = -28\end{array}$$

Summing them up:

$$6v= 24$$

With $$v = 4$$

Using any equation of the two I obtained $c$

$$c=\frac{52-9\times 4}{2}= \frac{52-36}{2}=\frac{16}{2}=8$$

And using the first equation:

$$t+v+c=19$$

$$t = 19 -\left(v+c\right)=19 - \left(4 + 8 \right) = 19 - 12 = 7$$

Therefore the number of tv cameras is $7$. Although what it was asked the number of video consoles which I obtained first being $4$.

In my book there appears these alternatives.

$$\begin{array}{c} 1.\,7\,\textrm{units} \\
  2.\,4\,\textrm{units} \\
  3.\,6\,\textrm{units} \\
  4.\,5\,\textrm{units} \\
  5.\,8\,\textrm{units} \end{array}$$

I would select the second option $4$. But was it right what I've just did?. My method seem to obtain an answer, but I don't know if it could had been simplified any further. Therefore I hope someone can check if my steps are consistent and help me with an easier method.

Comment: The answer is right $\checkmark$. Your three equations are the right ones. And then there are multiple ways of calculation. But I don´t see that there exists a way to simplify much your way of calculation. What is very nice is that you have defined the variables.